# How to keep all columns in a single ion-row in Ionic >= 2

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2, flexbox

I have a page in my ionic 2 application where I what a gird of items, where each item takes a single row.

A simplified example can be seen at [this plkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/kf5l67?p=preview)

Looking at the first row, I have 3 columns (red, gray, and orange).

[image]

I want the first two columns to stay fixed width, and have the last column take up the rest of the row. If the text is too long, I just want it to truncate and show ellipsis  (which I do using the `style='white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis`

Now, if I shrink the width of the page, the last column moved to be under the other rows....

[image]

Is there a way to have this third column stay in the same row, and just show the ellipsis once it runs out of room there (ie like below...)? I have tried everything!

[image]

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: what is your current html?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with this solution:

Apply following class to last column:

```
 .last-col{
        width: 1%;
 }
```

---

**Reasoning:** here we are overriding **.col class**'s width which is specified to be 100 % by the framework and because of this overriding Third col initially gets 1% width of its container and then there comes magic(i.e flex-grow: 1) attribute from the .col class which does all the trick.

*flex-grow definition*: It tells what amount of the **available space** (now we have available space because we have only specified/used 4px+ 30px+ 1% ) inside the flex container the item should take up.

```
.col {
    position: relative;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%; // we are overriding this field
    margin: 0;
    min-height: 1px;
    flex-basis: 0;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: @sanndeep thankyou! This does exactly what I am after. Also good to know what is actually doing the 'magic' (the flex-grow)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to add `col-auto` to they last col input in the row. [REF](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/grid/Grid/#variable-width)

```
<ion-row>
  <ion-col col-1> 1 </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-2> image </ion-col>
  <ion-col col-auto> aaaaaazzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzazazaaaa </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: I had tried using a combination off all these attributes, but unfortunately this does not do what I was after. The  `width: 1%` as in the first answer does the trick